# How to access my Stripe secret from azure key vault to inject into checkout.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, razor-pages

I'm developing a web app in dotnet 6 C# core razor pages.
I have setup an Azure key vault with my Stripe Api Key and Publishable Key.
I use the following code to access the key from the Key Vault.

```
public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
PublicKey = _configuration["PublishableKey"].ToString();
```

This code I have tested and it does return the Publishable Key.
I then need to inject that key into a javascript file checkout.js.

```
const stripe = Stripe('');
```

I tried this in the cshtml file,

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@Configuration["PublishableKey"].ToString()
```

That worked in the cshtml file.
I then tried this in the javerscript file checkout.js.

```
 const stripe = Stripe('@Configuration["PublishableKey"].ToString()')
```

I also tried.

```
@Model.PublicKey
```

But neither returned the key.
How do I reference this key in the javascript file?
Your help would be appreciated Thank-you.

Comment: writing an ajax request to your backend to read the key maybe an option